# react-native-ble-plx with Expo Run - Failed to build

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ble-plx

Finally the long waited support for Bluetooth is covered by Expo team:
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1

But when I run `expo run:ios` on Mac, I get an error - **value of optional type 'CBService?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'CBService'**:

[image: error messages]

The project is fresh, I just followed the instructions from Evan Bacon:

- `expo init`
- `expo add react-native-ble-plx @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx expo-dev-client`
  Add `@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx` to the expo.plugins array in your **app.json**.
- `expo run:ios -d` --> Gives me error.

The build works fine for android.